# Boost.Spirit.Qi: Defining a combination of too many parsers reaches template instantiation limit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

This is a valid (and compilable) parser combination:

```
lit("foo") | lit("bar") | lit("baz")
```

But when it comes to around **200-400** binary concatenation, it fails.

This is the example error output:

```
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
```

Yes, of course. I love you, compiler.
And the *actual* error is this:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/proto/detail/preprocessed/matches_.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::proto::detail::matches_<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::bitwise_or,
```

... `bitwise_or` continues forever.

I am quite sure that this is the nature of the expression template.
Quoting from Spirit's document:

```
Spirit pushes the C++ compiler hard.
```

lol.

---

So... Is there an efficient & simple-enough way to achieve the logically equivalent combined parser?
I've thought of the famous Nabialek trick, but it won't fit; it is for caching k-v pairs lazily and not for generating parser itself (if my understandings are correct).

Comment: A quick workaround I've found is to define a parser which parses the entire string unconditionally and then use phx::if_ to check whether the attribute matches any of the values inside a pre-defined static const vector<string>, and construct a variant<DesiredType, FallbackType> inside a semantic action. But obviously this is not a smart solution.

Comment: ...and I'd really like to avoid using -ftemplate-depth=99999.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you want? If you really just need `lit("foo")|lit("bar")|lit("baz")|...` a [`qi::symbols`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html) may be what you want, but it seems you actually need something more complex...

Comment: Well, qi::symbols is a parser which receives a keyword and returns an associated value, right? I need something similar to qi::symbols but one returning the keyword itself. Maybe I should have used qi::string instead of qi::lit for the example. But also, lit-equivalent approach (that synthesizes no attribute) is welcome too. That might solve the problem's root. The root is: I want to generally avoid this "big bang" caused by creating very much complex parser.

Comment: ...and giving same values for qi::symbols's both k-v like this: `sym.add("kw1", "kw1")("kw2", "kw2")("kw3", "kw3");` looks very ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `symbols<>`. If you want to propagate the matched input, use `raw[]`

Here's a sample that parses *and matches* all keywords from [rfc3092](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a736098ebe809e8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using     It = std::string::const_iterator;

int main() {

    qi::symbols<char> much;

    for (auto kw : {"bar", "baz", "qux", "quux", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"})
        much.add(kw);

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> match_much = qi::raw [ much ];

    much.for_each([&](std::string const& kw, qi::unused_type) {
        std::string matched;
        assert(qi::parse(kw.begin(), kw.end(), match_much, matched));
        assert(kw == matched);
    });
}
```

Comment: The combination of `symbols<>` and `raw[]` was the trick! Thanks a lot!